# What is this trick called?

Tags: calculus, gaussian-integral

Let $f$ be a positive $\mathcal C^2$ function defined on $[-1,1]$, with a maximum of $1$ attained only at $0$, and a negative second derivative at $0$ equal to $-\alpha$

Then $$ \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)^n\, \mathrm dx \approx \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\alpha n}}$$

I remember that it was proven by approximating the function in a neighborhood of $0$ by a Gaussian function. But I can't remember the name of the approximation.

Comment: Laplace's method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace's_method

Comment: It's not really a trick.

Comment: @zhw. Sorry, but I didn't know what to call it.